# About java ByteArrayOutputStream class

Tags: java, arrays, image, processing

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/...icon.jpg"));

// this writes the bufferedImage into a byte array called resultingBytes
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", byteArrayOut);

byte[] resultingBytes = byteArrayOut.toByteArray();
```

I use the above code to get a JEPG image as a byte array. I want to know what exactly is in this byte array. Does this array contain any file header information or just pixel values? And for example, if I want to reverse this image's color, what is a good way to do so?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ByteArrayOutputStream contains whatever you wrote to it. Nothing more, nothing less. So your question is *really* about ImageIO.write(). Which writes out an encoding of an image according to the encoding type you supply. Which was JPEG.

Answer (score 3):

It's a complete JPEG file, in memory.

EDIT: If you want to manipulate pixel data as an array, you may find `Raster` more helpful:

E.g.:

```
Raster raster = bufferedImage.getData();
```

You can then call one of the `Raster.getPixels` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you read real pixel values. The JPEG information is much harder to do anything with!

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    String u = "http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png";

    BufferedImage old = ImageIO.read(new URL(u));
    BufferedImage inverted = new BufferedImage(old.getWidth(),
                                               old.getHeight(),
                                               BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);


    for (int y = 0; y < old.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < old.getWidth(); x++) {
            Color oldColor = new Color(old.getRGB(x, y));

            // reverse all but the alpha channel
            Color invertedColor = new Color(255 - oldColor.getRed(),
                                            255 - oldColor.getGreen(),
                                            255 - oldColor.getBlue());

            inverted.setRGB(x, y, invertedColor.getRGB());
        }
    }

    ImageIO.write(inverted, "png", new File("test.png"));
}
```